# trouble reading a 2D array of characters in C?

Tags: c

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void acceptMaze(char maze[ROW][COLOUMN], int nrows, int ncols)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"I = %d",i);
        for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) 
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"J = %d",j);
            scanf("%c",&maze[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

wel while entering data it says`i =0 j=0j=1` .So you see the j=0 doesn't remains.I am using a linux system .Can anyone fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that the `%c` conversion specifier doesn't skip whitespace.  If there's a newline stuck in the input stream from a previous input operation, the `scanf` call will read that and assign it to `maze[i][j]`.

Here's one workaround:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; i < nrows; j++)
  {
    int c;
    do c = getchar(); while (isspace(c));
    maze[i][j] = c;
  }
}
```

The line `do c = getchar(); while (isspace(c))` will read input characters until you hit a non-whitespace character.

**EDIT**

Ugh, I just realized one ugly flaw of this scheme; if you *want* to a assign a whitespace character like a blank to your maze, this won't work as written.  Of course, you can just add to the condition expression:

```
do c = getchar(); while (isspace(c) && c != ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to output some newlines to make it easier for the user to read.  How about:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void acceptMaze(char maze[][],int nrows,int ncols)
{

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<nrows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<ncols;j++) 
        {
            printf("\nenter %d,%d: ",i, j);
            scanf("%c",&maze[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The enter key is being accepted as input for half of your queries. Say you prompt for i = 0, j = 0, and the user enters '5' followed by the enter key. Scanf inserts '5' into maze[0][0], and in the next iteration of the loop, it sees that the enter key is still in the buffer, so it inserts that into maze[0][1].

You need to flush the input after every scanf. One solution is to `#include <iostream>` and call `std::cin.ignore()` after each scanf.

Comment: That solution cannot be applied to a C problem :)